# Custom Device & Vuforia

Tags: integration, vuforia

I'm interesting in integrating a custom device with Vuforia. I've read this article:
https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/vuforia-support-custom-devices-using-vuforia-driver

which implies that your custom device must have a camera and a 6-DoF tracker. Personally, I find this quite surprising as although most mobile devices might have an IMU package consisting of gyros and accelerometers, I'm pretty sure most do not have an absolute position and angular tracker (other than perhaps integrating accelerometer outputs to achieve a position which would most likely drift). Does anyone have any further information on this or has anyone any experience of integrating for a custom event?

Thanks,
Dave

I've googled all the relevant content I can find.

Comment: Providing 6DoF device poses is not mandatory. Several Vuforia features work just from camera frames. The limitations from the documentation are: `Device poses from a device tracker are necessary for Area Targets to function, and without device poses Model Target tracking stability is significantly reduced`

Comment: Regarding device tracker availability... most reasonably popular mobile devices already have a platform device tracker like ARKit for iOS and ARCore for Android and Vuforia is going to pick it up without any need to implement a driver. Which custom device are you trying to integrate?

Comment: We are developing a Windows 10 PC-based system with attached peripherals. ie. cameras, IMU, etc...

Comment: There are companies like slamcore.com which offer device tracker solutions. For experimentation ORBSlam is also an option https://openslam-org.github.io/orbslam.html

Answer (score 0):

6-dof tracking is required only if you want to use ModelTargets/Area Targets or extended tracking with Vuforia Engine. Without IMU data, you will be limited to Image tracking.

If I remember correctly you should be able to integrate custom devices which do not have an IMU package.

Hope this helps.
S